# How to slide or .animate multiple items in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've coded a show/hide for a list of items as seen here https://jsfiddle.net/qbxtkyzu/. I'm trying to animate (slide In and Out) the same items instead of just having them pop in and out.

```
<div id="main">
    <div>
    Base Text /
    </div>
    <div id="1" class="trip">Item1</div>
    <div id="2" class="trip">Item2</div>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
var $elem = $('#main .trip'), l = $elem.length, i = 0;
function go() {
$elem.eq(i % l).delay(5000).show(30, function() {
    $elem.eq(i % l).delay(5000).fadeOut(30, go);
    i++;
  })
}

go();
```

and the css:

```
.trip { display: none}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for it to slide in from the left, you could probably do something like this:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.trip { 
  transition: left 2s;
  position:absolute;
  left: -100%;
}

.trip.visible {
  left: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xs7b6hxe/

Comment: Thanks user1771700 This is what I was looking for! thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter both `show` and `fadeOut` functions get is the time (in milliseconds) to run the animation.

In you case - you have `30`, which are 30 milliseconds - pretty fast.
If you change that to (lets say) 1000, you will see the animation:

```js
var $elem = $('#main .trip'), l = $elem.length, i = 0;

function go() {
    $elem.eq(i % l).delay(2000).show(1000, function() {
        $elem.eq(i % l).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, go);
        i++;
    })
}

go();
```

```css
.trip { display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div>
    Born To /
    </div>
    <div id="1" class="trip">Item1</div>
    <div id="2" class="trip">Item2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dekel you are right. Now I just need the text to actually slide in from the left direction inside the div. I'm still playing with the .animate function to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use CSS transitions for this. So

```
.trip{
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.trip.show{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Then just add the class "show" to the elements rather than animating them in JS.

Comment: Thanks did this animate it sliding in instead of fading for you?

Comment: This would be a fade in. You could slide it in by replacing `opacity: 0;` with `line-height: 0` and `opacity: 1;` with `line-height: auto;`